# Are header files same or different for multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, boost, header-files

When ever we create a header file for a dll or some library.It mite have platform specific code.So generally are header files distributed according to platforms?(Linux,Mac,Windows)

What about the header files of boost libraries or wxwidgets libraries?

Comment: I would say the `#ifdef` method with single header is easier than maintaining several headers or having extra tool to generate header depending on platform.

Comment: I agree to that. I was wondering about the third party libraries which I mite use in my project. Like boost for C++ and wxwidgets. Is it a standard to distribute common header files for all platforms?

Comment: If you wonder about boost and wxwidgets, why don't you just look at their headers?

Comment: @nwp I agree to that. Looking at one header files of the library mite not indicate all related libraries header files be like that. I was thinking on those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a library, you are generally best off when header files are *identical* for all platforms. However, for most practical libraries there are some system dependencies which mandate differences. Users of a library are best isolated from any differences to start with and it may be reasonable to encapsulate the platform specifics into the implementation, e.g., using the Private Implementation idiom.

Where system dependencies creep into the interface there may be variation in declarations in the header. For example, the way networking infrastructure is accessed is system dependent and the involved types and function calls differ between platforms.  If the data structures are embedded directly into a user-visible class (e.g., improve performance) or functions are called from a header, e.g., because they are called from a function template, there may be differences.

My preference on dealing with differences in headers is to use conditional compilation and keep the same header and interface. In most cases I try to further centralize the use of conditional compilation to one location for each entity different to avoid conditional compilation as much as possible: when another configuration becomes necessary, I want to update as few places as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally implementation of interfaces  in header file should be different as per platforms (Linux,Mac,Windows) .In a standard implementation , header file should be same .
Code for different platforms is separated using compilation flag .
Thats the ideal case , however some poor library may have even different headers.

Comment: Thanks sachin for the answer,that was helpful. Is there a way to know if third party which which i going to use distributes common or different set of header files based on platform without having to go through looking at header files myself.

Comment: I'd say, headers are _ideally_ identical! However, to work optimally on different platforms they may need to be different...